# Comment flags on SO not working properly with Opera

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, comments, opera

I tried to upvote a comment on SO, but when I moved the mouse over the greyed out up arrow, it disappeared.  I can click on the blank space and an upvote is counted.  Now using the links at the bottom of the page I open up Server Fault, go to a comment on a question there and the comment flags work as expected.  Meta, SuperUser also OK.

Version: 10.00
Build: 1750
Platform: Win32
System: WinXP Pro
Java: Sun JRE 1.6
Browser ID: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.2.15 Version/10.00

Is this a bug?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Try flushing your cache.

Comment: What do you know, that did it! Put it down to an Opera quirk.  Thanks for the tip random.  Put it in as an answer & I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Switching to rep-whore mode...*

Flushing your cache should fix it up. Since the JavaScript was still working, it's most likely a cache issue with the CSS swapping out the image of upvotedabilityness.

*There is no off position in the rep-whore mode!*

Comment: I should downvote this... ah, who cares :)

Comment: Thanks random.  Perhaps Meta isn't the best place for the answer, but at least it might help someone else via a search engine..

Comment: Meta is the best place for questions about how the rest of the sites work.